# wordpress custom post type comes with a page

Tags: wordpress, url, custom-post-type

When you goto http://www.classicandvintage.co.uk/car/rebecca/
it is using a custom post type of car that i created...

thing is, this page also exists and I have no idea where it is coming from?
http://www.classicandvintage.co.uk/car

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the page "Car",

is your top level (index.php) page, populating the page with all posts from that custom post type,

you could create a page template for that page, which lists all cars used for the weddings (which it is already) then show just the featured image from each post, instead of showing all the post info etc..

[[EDIT]]
or if you want to redirect it:

in your htaccess file you could add

redirect 301 /car http://www.classicandvintage.co.uk/

Comment: Any way to forward it on to the homepage or something?

Comment: ahhh thankyou good sir!!! did a header("") on it to forward to get_bloginf("url").